# How to plot country names on the globe, so the mesh will be aligned with the surfaces

Tags: three.js, linear-algebra

I'm trying to plot country names of the globe, so the text meshes will be aligned with the surface, but I'm failing to calculate proper rotations. For text I'm using THREE.TextGeometry. The name appears on the click of the mesh of the country at the point of intersection using raycasting. I'm lacking knowledge of how to turn these coordinates to proper rotation angles. I'm not posting my code, as it's complete mess and I believe for a knowldgeable person will be easier to explain how to achieve this in general.

Here is desired result:

[image: Here is desired result:]

Comment: Just a semi-related question as someone curious about this topic—do you have any experience or opinion with [Cesium.js](http://cesiumjs.org/) for this kind of thing?

Comment: What type of geometry for countries? Geometry or buffer geometry.

Comment: prisoner849, I'm using geometry, but I think it does not matter, because I'm getting coordinates of a point of intersection. I can remove countries and merely click on the sphere with the same results. The question is how to align text along the surface.

Comment: Ahmed, sorry, have zero experience with Cesium.

Comment: @Hamabama I've made an answer with an idea of using a face normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very interesting question.I have tried this way, we can regard the text as a plane. lets define a normal vector `n` from your sphere center(or position) to point on the sphere surface where you want to display text. I have a simple way to make normal vector right. 
1. put the text mesh on sphere center. `text.position.copy(sphere.position)`
2. make text to the point on sphere surface, `text.lookAt(point)`
3.relocate text to the point. `text.position.copy(point)`

Comment: That's interesting idea! I'll get back to you with the results! Thanks

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The other solution, which I tried (and which, of course, is not the ultimate), based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16268482/three-js-convert-face-normal-from-local-space-to-world-space). The idea is to use the normal of the face you intersect with the raycaster.

1. Obtain the point of intersection.
2. Obtain the face of intersection.
3. Obtain the normal of the face (2).
4. Get the normal (3) in world coordinates.
5. Set position of the text object as sum of point of intersection (1) and the normal in world coordinates (4).
6. Set lookAt() vector of the text object as sum of its position (5) and the normal in world coordinates (4).

Seems long, but actually it makes not so much of code:

```
var PGHelper = new THREE.PolarGridHelper(...); // let's imagine it's your text object ;)
var PGlookAt = new THREE.Vector3(); // point of lookAt for the "text" object

var normalMatrix = new THREE.Matrix3();
var worldNormal = new THREE.Vector3();
```

and in the animation loop:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++ ) {
    normalMatrix.getNormalMatrix( intersects[i].object.matrixWorld );
    worldNormal.copy(intersects[i].face.normal).applyMatrix3( normalMatrix ).normalize();

    PGHelper.position.addVectors(intersects[i].point, worldNormal);
    PGlookAt.addVectors(PGHelper.position, worldNormal);
    PGHelper.lookAt(PGlookAt);
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/bkwvg3xL/) exmaple

The method works with meshes of any geometry (checked with spheres and boxes though ;) ). And I'm sure there are another better methods.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, works fine! However, the solution above works also just fine and he posted it ahead of yours. But anyways thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome ) I have nothing against the post ahead of mine ) I've made this answer because it was interesting for myself )