# Parametric equations for sphere surface tangent plane

Tags: 3d, three.js, webgl, parametric-equations

Excuse my first post, it is literally that. I've been banging my head for three days trying to get squares to align properly on a sphere. Does anyone know the **parametric equations for the tangents of a plane**? See tangents X, Y and Z in  the code below...

[Here is the output for reference. My stupid face is there, as a bonus, for you all to hate on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKzFn.png)

The code is a part of a much larger library on multiple pages. It is kind of a distraction from the question. I have scoured math sites and StackOverflow for the answer.  I am baking the positional and rotational data into Float32 arrays before sending it to the renderer. So, lookAt and other THREE and WebGL functions won't work. I need the pure math solution.

```
this.sphere = function()
{
    var args = arguments[ 0 ];
    var offsets = offset( args.parameters.offsets );
    var arrays =
    {
        unique: [],
        position: [],
        rotation: []
    };
    var phi, theta;
    var x, y, z;
    var tangentX, tangentY, tangentZ;
    var pos = [];
    var d360 = Math.PI * 2;
    var d180 = Math.PI;
    var d90 = Math.PI / 2;
    var cap = false;

    for ( var p = 0; p <= args.parameters.stacks; p++ )
    {
        // stacks
        phi = d180 * p / args.parameters.stacks;

        for ( var t = 0; t < args.parameters.slices; t++ )
        {
            var predicate = true;

            // slices
            theta = d360 * t / args.parameters.slices;

            x = precision( Math.cos( theta ) * Math.sin( phi ), 3 ) * args.parameters.scale.x + offsets.position.x;
            y = precision( Math.cos( phi ), 3 )                     * args.parameters.scale.y + offsets.position.y;
            z = precision( Math.sin( theta ) * Math.sin( phi ), 3 ) * args.parameters.scale.z + offsets.position.z;

            pos = [ x, y, z ];

            // caps - both sin and cos are 0
            cap = !( precision( Math.sin( phi ), 0 ) || precision( Math.cos( theta ), 0 ) );

            /* This is my problem area ************************************/
            tangentX = - Math.sign( Math.sin( theta ) ) * Math.tan( y );
            tangentY = d90 - theta;
            tangentZ = 0;

            //if ( predicate ) console.log( p, t, degrees( theta ), degrees( tangentY ), Math.sign( Math.sin( phi ) ) );

            // add only once
            if ( !hash( arrays.unique, pos ) && predicate )
            {
                arrays.unique.push( pos );

                arrays.position.push( x, y, z );
                arrays.rotation.push( tangentX, tangentY, tangentZ );
            }
        }
    }

    return { position: new Float32Array( arrays.position ), rotation: new Float32Array( arrays.rotation ) };
};
```

Comment: Post your code as text, so we can test it. You should also put the main part of your code in your question too.

Comment: I see your code is not in three.js, and I don't how you define and use the rotation. But, in three.js what you need is get the right rotation of your planes, and you can refer [How to plot country names on the globe, so the mesh will be aligned with the surfaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41774112/how-to-plot-country-names-on-the-globe-so-the-mesh-will-be-aligned-with-the-sur/41775276#41775276).

Comment: From Stack Overflow's Help: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.***  Please put the text of your code in the question, not a screenshot of the text.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to put cubes on a sphere is to use a good `lookAt` function, one that returns a world matrix not an inverse world matrix (although if you have one that returns an inverse world matrix you can invert it to get a world matrix)

Just pick a point on the sphere then call

```
const positionOnSphere = (pick a point on the sphere)
const target = [0, 0, 0];  // look at the center of the sphere
const up = [0, 1, 0];      // will work as long as you're not putting 
                           // sphere at the exact poles
const worldMatrix = yourMathLibsLookAtFunction(positionOnSphere, target, up);
```

Or

```
const invMatrix = yourMathLibsInverseLookAtFunction(positionOnSphere, target, up);
const worldMatrix = yourMathLibsInverseFunction(invMatrix);
```

```js
"use strict";
twgl.setDefaults({attribPrefix: "a_"});
const m4 = twgl.m4;
const v3 = twgl.v3;
const gl = twgl.getWebGLContext(document.getElementById("c"));
const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, ["vs", "fs"]);
const bufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createCubeBufferInfo(gl, 2);

// adapted from http://stackoverflow.com/a/26127012/128511
function fibonacciSphere(samples, i) {
  const rnd = 1.;  
  const offset = 2. / samples;
  const increment = Math.PI * (3. - Math.sqrt(5.));

  //  for i in range(samples):
  const y = ((i * offset) - 1.) + (offset / 2.);
  const r = Math.sqrt(1. - Math.pow(y ,2.));

  const phi = ((i + rnd) % samples) * increment;

  const x = Math.cos(phi) * r;
  const z = Math.sin(phi) * r;

  return [x, y, z];
}

// Shared values
const lightWorldPosition = [1, 8, -10];
const lightColor = [1, 1, 1, 1];
const camera = m4.identity();
const view = m4.identity();
const viewProjection = m4.identity();

const objects = [];
const drawObjects = [];
const numObjects = 100;
for (var ii = 0; ii < numObjects; ++ii) {

  const position = v3.mulScalar(fibonacciSphere(numObjects, ii + 1), 10);
  const target = [0, 0, 0];
  const up = [0, 1, 0];
  
  const world = m4.lookAt(position, target, up);
  m4.scale(world, [1, 1, 0.1], world);

  const uniforms = {
    u_lightWorldPos: lightWorldPosition,
    u_lightColor: lightColor,
    u_diffuseColor: [1, ii / numObjects, 0, 1],
    u_specular: [1, 1, 1, 1],
    u_shininess: 50,
    u_specularFactor: 1,
    u_viewInverse: camera,
    u_world: world,
    u_worldInverseTranspose: m4.identity(),
    u_worldViewProjection: m4.identity(),
  };
  drawObjects.push({
    programInfo: programInfo,
    bufferInfo: bufferInfo,
    uniforms: uniforms,
  });
  objects.push({
    uniforms: uniforms,
  });
}

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;
  twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  const projection = m4.perspective(30 * Math.PI / 180, gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight, 0.5, 100);
  const radius = 25;
  const eye = [Math.cos(time) * radius, Math.sin(time * 0.3) * radius, Math.sin(time) * radius];
  const target = [0, 0, 0];
  const up = [0, 1, 0];

  m4.lookAt(eye, target, up, camera);
  m4.inverse(camera, view);
  m4.multiply(projection, view, viewProjection);

  objects.forEach(function(obj) {
    const uni = obj.uniforms;
    const world = uni.u_world;
    m4.transpose(m4.inverse(world, uni.u_worldInverseTranspose), uni.u_worldInverseTranspose);
    m4.multiply(viewProjection, uni.u_world, uni.u_worldViewProjection);
  });

  twgl.drawObjectList(gl, drawObjects);

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
canvas {
    display: block;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script id="vs" type="notjs">
uniform mat4 u_worldViewProjection;
uniform vec3 u_lightWorldPos;
uniform mat4 u_world;
uniform mat4 u_viewInverse;
uniform mat4 u_worldInverseTranspose;

attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec3 a_normal;
attribute vec2 a_texcoord;

varying vec4 v_position;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
varying vec3 v_normal;
varying vec3 v_surfaceToLight;
varying vec3 v_surfaceToView;

void main() {
  v_texCoord = a_texcoord;
  v_position = (u_worldViewProjection * a_position);
  v_normal = (u_worldInverseTranspose * vec4(a_normal, 0)).xyz;
  v_surfaceToLight = u_lightWorldPos - (u_world * a_position).xyz;
  v_surfaceToView = (u_viewInverse[3] - (u_world * a_position)).xyz;
  gl_Position = v_position;
}
</script>
<script id="fs" type="notjs">
precision mediump float;

varying vec4 v_position;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
varying vec3 v_normal;
varying vec3 v_surfaceToLight;
varying vec3 v_surfaceToView;

uniform vec4 u_lightColor;
uniform vec4 u_diffuseColor;
uniform vec4 u_specular;
uniform float u_shininess;
uniform float u_specularFactor;

vec4 lit(float l ,float h, float m) {
  return vec4(1.0,
              abs(l),//max(l, 0.0),
              (l > 0.0) ? pow(max(0.0, h), m) : 0.0,
              1.0);
}

void main() {
  vec3 a_normal = normalize(v_normal);
  vec3 surfaceToLight = normalize(v_surfaceToLight);
  vec3 surfaceToView = normalize(v_surfaceToView);
  vec3 halfVector = normalize(surfaceToLight + surfaceToView);
  vec4 litR = lit(dot(a_normal, surfaceToLight),
                    dot(a_normal, halfVector), u_shininess);
  vec4 outColor = vec4((
  u_lightColor * (u_diffuseColor * litR.y +
                u_specular * litR.z * u_specularFactor)).rgb,
      u_diffuseColor.a);
  gl_FragColor = outColor;
}
</script>
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/3.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
```